# Notation of variable range with i as integer

Tags: excel, vba, integer, range

I was wondering if anyone could help me to write the following code correctly so VBA will accept it and be able to run it.

```
Dim i As Integer

If Range ("A1") = i Then Range ("Bi:Ei").Select
```

The purpose is: If I enter value 5 for example in Cell A1 (i=5 in this case), then `Range("B5:E5")` would be selected to continue further actions like copy-pasting for example. So the moment I enter 5 in Cell A1, I click on the button which runs the code with the purpose to return the results in `Range(B5:E5)` to be pasted in a certain cell.

I tried to write `Range ("Bi:Ei")` as `Range ("B:E" & Cstr(i))` but I'm probably lacking some experience here.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe you mean `Range("B" & i & ":E" & i)` ?? And if `i` is going to hold the row number, you are going to want to use a `Long` instead of an `Integer` to avoid future overflow errors.

Comment: Thank you for replying, your notation as mentioned above works, thank you (I got many errors with other ways of putting it). You're probably right about the 'Long'. Because the purpose is to be able to select the range and paste it elsewhere. At the moment it's just the number 5 for example I enter in Cell A1 that is the result, but I actually need the whole range from B5:E5 (it's a set of numbers and text). i is indeed the row number.

Comment: I posted a new question with the complete purpose, maybe you know what I'm missing? Thank you.